# How to remove (.php) extension containing query parameter in the url in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

### Help Me to remove (.php) extension

I have an index page (*index.php*) that has some hyperlinks that goes to `project_details.php?name=$name.`

So the current link is like (`http://localhost/development/project_details.php?name=$name`).

Now I want to change the url to (`http://localhost/development/$name`) and then in *project_dtails.php*, I want to get the name.

How shall i do this?

Comment: _“How shall i do this?”_ - you shall start by doing your own proper research, instead of asking “how do I do this” questions here in this place about topics that have been discussed countless times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `.htaccess` .

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ project_details.php?name=$1
```

Now you can access the parameter(name) like this in `project_details.php` file

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: Not working.
Its showing "The requested URL was not found on this server. Error 404".

Comment: index.php -> <a href="project_details.php?name=Savoy><img src=" "></a>
.htaccess ->
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ project_details.php?name=$1

project_details.php -> <?php echo $_GET['name']; exit;?>

Comment: Still not working ."Object Not found.The requested URL was not found on this server.Error 404".
The url is working fine.Its coming like 'localhost/php/development/Savoy". But I cannot get the value like $_GET['name'] in project_details.php
I have my folder directory like htdocs->php->development-> index.php, project_details.php, .htaccess

Comment: Keep `.htaccess` file in development folder.

Comment: .htaccess is already inside the development folder.But why its not working?

Comment: Yes now I can get the value in project_details.php. But when I click the hyperlink button,  the link is showing like 
'http://localhost:8080/php/development/project_details.php?name=Savoy'.
i want it like 'http://localhost:8080/php/development/Savoy'

Comment: The above code is not working when there are more pages and folder 
My folder structure
 admin
 assets
.htaccess
 index.php
 project_details.php
 contact.php
 category.php

Answer (score 0):

A solution to do something like this is to create a router wich will matchs some URL and include the right files based on that. For example if the project name is myProject you can have `http://localhost/development/myProject`.

There is an example here : https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/

I hope I have been helpful.